# Group items in Python

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I am trying to group all this according to their languages

```
        [('Lanice', 'Montre', 'bayurzx@gmail.com', 'en'),
         ('Do', 'Ji', 'bomolumo@yahoo.com', 'es'), 
         ('Edem', 'Lamoine', 'yemiade5700@gmail.com', 'zh-Hans'), 
         ('Celine', 'Jerry', 'bomolumo30@gmail.com', 'ar'), 
         ('Kerry', 'Mabs', 'bomol@gmail.com', 'ar'), 
         ('Tom', 'Maine', 'yemiade@gmail.com', 'fr'), 
         ('Mary', 'Maine', 'yemiade5700@gmail.com', 'fr'), 
         ('John', 'Doe', 'johndoe@gmail.com', 'bg'), 
         ('Johnny','Bravo', 'johnnybravo@gmail.com', 'en')]
```

The output would be something like this:
output =

```
     [{"en": ['johnnybravo@gmail.com', 'bayurzx@gmail.com']},
      {"es": ["bomolumo@yahoo.com"]},
      {"zh-Hans": ['yemiade5700@gmail.com']},
      ...]
```

making the languages dict unique

Comment: That data structure makes little sense. A single dict with the languages as key strikes me as more useful.

Comment: Have you tried anything you’re having trouble with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = [('Lanice', 'Montre', 'bayurzx@gmail.com', 'en'),
         ('Do', 'Ji', 'bomolumo@yahoo.com', 'es'),
         ('Edem', 'Lamoine', 'yemiade5700@gmail.com', 'zh-Hans'),
         ('Celine', 'Jerry', 'bomolumo30@gmail.com', 'ar'),
         ('Kerry', 'Mabs', 'bomol@gmail.com', 'ar'),
         ('Tom', 'Maine', 'yemiade@gmail.com', 'fr'),
         ('Mary', 'Maine', 'yemiade5700@gmail.com', 'fr'),
         ('John', 'Doe', 'johndoe@gmail.com', 'bg'),
         ('Johnny','Bravo', 'johnnybravo@gmail.com', 'en')]
```

Maybe it helps:

```
output = {_user[-1]:[] for _user in data}

[output[_user[-1]].append(_user[2]) for _user in data]

print(output)
```

result:

```
{
'en': ['bayurzx@gmail.com', 'johnnybravo@gmail.com'],
'es': ['bomolumo@yahoo.com'],
'zh-Hans': ['yemiade5700@gmail.com'],
'ar': ['bomolumo30@gmail.com', 'bomol@gmail.com'],
'fr': ['yemiade@gmail.com', 'yemiade5700@gmail.com'],
'bg': ['johndoe@gmail.com']
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

output = defaultdict(list)
for *_, mail, lang in data:
    output[lang].append(mail)

defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'en': ['bayurzx@gmail.com', 'johnnybravo@gmail.com'], 
                             'es': ['bomolumo@yahoo.com'], 
                             'zh-Hans': ['yemiade5700@gmail.com'], 
                             'ar': ['bomolumo30@gmail.com', 'bomol@gmail.com'], 
                             'fr': ['yemiade@gmail.com', 'yemiade5700@gmail.com'], 
                             'bg': ['johndoe@gmail.com']})
```